# Window size change causes an overwriting of my bar chart - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a simple GUI made with `PyQt5` with two `QWidgets` and two pushbuttons. Each pushbutton generates a bar chart. This part works perfectly but when the size of the window changes, the left bar chart overwrites the one on the right side (i.e. I have the same bar chart twice). How can I prevent this overwritting?

Backend code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from network_view import Ui_MainWindow
import sys

class Run_script(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Run_script,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.view_graph1)
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.view_graph2)
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.graph1 = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graph1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.graph2 = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graph2, 1, 1, 1, 1)

    def view_graph1(self):
        self.figure.clf()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
        x2 = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]
        y2 = [15, 25, 35, 45, 55]
        self.axes.bar(x1,y1,width=0.40)
        self.axes.bar(x2,y2,width=0.40)
        self.graph1.draw()

    def view_graph2(self):
        self.figure.clf()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
        x2 = [1.25, 2.25, 3.25, 4.25, 5.25]
        y2 = [15, 25, 35, 45, 55]
        x3 = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]
        y3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        self.axes.bar(x1,y1,width=0.40)
        self.axes.bar(x2,y2,width=0.40)
        self.axes.bar(x3,y3,width=0.40)
        self.graph2.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    prog = Run_script()
    prog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Frontend code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget1.setObjectName("widget1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.widget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget2.setObjectName("widget2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you

Comment: That is because they *are* the same. You are using the same figure for both. In order to fix this (1) do not use `pyplot` at all in PyQt GUIs (2) create two figures, one for each figure canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused because you are using the same `plt.figure()`, so when you use `clf()` clean the drawing and add a new plot, that's why you think it is overwritten.

> Why do not you see that effect immediately after pressing the button?

Because it has not been notified to the view that you have to apply the changes, but as soon as you change the size it is repainted with the updated data, the same thing you could see when using `update()`.

A possible solution is each each `FigureCanvas` have a `plt.figure()`:

```
class Run_script(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Run_script,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.view_graph1)
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.view_graph2)
        self.figure1 = plt.figure()
        self.graph1 = FigureCanvas(self.figure1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graph1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.figure2 = plt.figure()
        self.graph2 = FigureCanvas(self.figure2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graph2, 1, 1, 1, 1)

    def view_graph1(self):
        self.figure1.clf()
        axes = self.figure1.add_subplot(111)
        x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
        x2 = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]
        y2 = [15, 25, 35, 45, 55]
        axes.bar(x1,y1,width=0.40)
        axes.bar(x2,y2,width=0.40)
        self.graph1.draw()

    def view_graph2(self):
        self.figure2.clf()
        axes = self.figure2.add_subplot(111)
        x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
        x2 = [1.25, 2.25, 3.25, 4.25, 5.25]
        y2 = [15, 25, 35, 45, 55]
        x3 = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]
        y3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        axes.bar(x1,y1,width=0.40)
        axes.bar(x2,y2,width=0.40)
        axes.bar(x3,y3,width=0.40)
        self.graph2.draw()
```

A better implementation is to create your own canvas:

```
class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)

class Run_script(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Run_script,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.view_graph1)
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.view_graph2)
        self.graph1 = MyCanvas()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graph1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.graph2 = MyCanvas()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graph2, 1, 1, 1, 1)

    def view_graph1(self):
        self.graph1.figure.clf()
        axes = self.graph1.figure.add_subplot(111)
        x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
        x2 = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]
        y2 = [15, 25, 35, 45, 55]
        axes.bar(x1,y1,width=0.40)
        axes.bar(x2,y2,width=0.40)
        self.graph1.draw()

    def view_graph2(self):
        self.graph2.figure.clf()
        axes = self.graph2.figure.add_subplot(111)
        x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
        x2 = [1.25, 2.25, 3.25, 4.25, 5.25]
        y2 = [15, 25, 35, 45, 55]
        x3 = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]
        y3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        axes.bar(x1,y1,width=0.40)
        axes.bar(x2,y2,width=0.40)
        axes.bar(x3,y3,width=0.40)
        self.graph2.draw()
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented already you have only one figure in the programm. Hence both plots *are* the same. You would need to have two different figures. Additionally, do not use pyplot in GUIs because this allows you to easily run into problems like this.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class Run_script(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Run_script,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.view_graph1)
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.view_graph2)
        self.figure1 = Figure()
        self.graph1 = FigureCanvas(self.figure1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graph1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.figure2 = Figure()
        self.graph2 = FigureCanvas(self.figure2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graph2, 1, 1, 1, 1)

    def view_graph1(self):
        self.figure1.clf()
        self.axes = self.figure1.add_subplot(111)
        x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
        x2 = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]
        y2 = [15, 25, 35, 45, 55]
        self.axes.bar(x1,y1,width=0.40)
        self.axes.bar(x2,y2,width=0.40)
        self.graph1.draw()

    def view_graph2(self):
        self.figure2.clf()
        self.axes = self.figure2.add_subplot(111)
        x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
        x2 = [1.25, 2.25, 3.25, 4.25, 5.25]
        y2 = [15, 25, 35, 45, 55]
        x3 = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]
        y3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        self.axes.bar(x1,y1,width=0.40)
        self.axes.bar(x2,y2,width=0.40)
        self.axes.bar(x3,y3,width=0.40)
        self.graph2.draw()
```